# Listing all instances of a document model that belongs to user through group relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I basically followed the ROR guide, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association, to create the relationship models as shown below.

Because of the through association, I figured that @user.trips would give you both the trips that the user created and the trips that belong to the user. However, when I do `@user.trips.count` in console, the result was only the number of trips that the users created; the trips that belonged to the user through the 'group' association was not counted.

Question: How do I get my view to display both the trips that the user created and the trips that the user belongs to through 'group'?

user/show.html.erb

```
<% unless @user.all_trips.empty? %>
  <% @user.all_trips.each do |trip| %>
     <!-- Content -->
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_trips, :through => :groups,
                         :source   => :trip
  has_many :trips, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :groups

  def all_trips
    self.trips | self.group_trips
  end


end
```

trip.rb

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :traveldeal
  has_many :groups

  has_many :users, :through => :groups
end
```

group.rb

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trip
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Thanks!

Edit: Modified code per TSherif's partial solution.
Edit 2: Fixed up the all_trips method. Everything appears to work for me at this point.

Comment: BTW, I think it's probably a better idea not to change around the code too much in your question. Now, if someone has the same problem you had, they won't be able to tell.

Comment: Will keep this in mind for next time; I figured it would be more helpful if people saw a working solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh! I think I get what you're trying to do and why it's a problem. I was wondering why `has_many :trips` was called *twice*. But from what I understand, you have two **different** `User`-`Trip` relationships. These two can't have the same name, otherwise one will hide the other. Try something like this:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_trips, :through => :groups,
                         :class_name   => "Trip"
  has_many :trips, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :groups

  def all_trips
    Trip.joins(:groups).where({:user_id => self.id} | {:groups => {:user_id => self.id}})
  end
end
```

Or if you're using an older version of Rails that doesn't have `MetaWhere`:

```
def all_trips
  Trip.joins(:groups).where("(trips.user_id = ?) OR (groups.user_id = ?)", self.id, self.id)
end
```

Comment: I haven't been sure that the Rails 3 joins method could take associations.  Also, you seem to be passing an expression to the where method.  Where can I read up on more information about these methods?

api.rubyonrails.org and apidoc.com document the where method as:

where(opts, *rest)

So the only documentation I have is from the Rails 2.3 find method.

Comment: The expression in the `where` clause uses `MetaWhere` syntax. You can get info about it here: http://erniemiller.org/projects/metawhere/

Comment: Thanks.  I'm very appreciative.  Still, the Rails documentation would be a better place to find all this, instead of hunting around for stuff like this. :)

Comment: Totally agree. I've been using Rails 3 for about a year now and just accidentally found out about this stuff last week watching a Railscast (which is a great resource, btw, if you aren't already using it).

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do, Tsherif. However, I keep getting this error `undefined method `|' for {:user_id=>4}:Hash` when I try to load groups/new.html.erb in the view.

Comment: Oh, maybe you're using an older version of Rails, that doesn't have this syntax. I'll add something to the answer that should work anywhere.

Comment: The new code works in that the view is displayed, but now @user.all_trips.count only returns the trips that the user has through group.

Comment: `def all_trips
  Trip.joins(:groups).where("(trips.user_id = ?) OR (groups.user_id = ?)", self.id, self.id) | trips
end`  This code I pasted seems to do the trick. Can you verify that my logic is correct? Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Mmm... all that does is a set union between two separate queries. If you want to go that way, just do `def all_trips; self.trips | self.group_trips; end`. But are you saying that `friend.all_trips.count` produces something different from `friend.all_trips.all.size`? Can you post the SQL generated from the first query (from your execution log), so I can take a look at it. I think it should be working. Look for the one with `SELECT COUNT(...`.

Comment: I had to change to this in the user model `has_many :group_trips, :through => :tripusers, :source => :trips` for `def all_trips; self.trips | self.group_trips; end` to work, but this is exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate the help!